# Symfony3, creating entity without mapping all table fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have a database table which has a lot of fields. I want to create an Entity which maps only to few of those fields.
Is there a practical way to achieve that?

When I try to make an entity and mapping it via annotations, the `doctrine:schema:validate` command says that the entity is not in sync, and is right.
When I try to make a `doctrine:schema:update` it automatically drops all the fields that the entity doesn't have. I want that the schema update command updates only the fields written in my entity class.

Comment: There definitely is.

Comment: There are a number of ways entities can be mapped with symfony/doctrine. Your question is too vague. It should be something covered in beginner tutorials on the topic or you might be able to figure it out simply looking at some of your existing entities..

Comment: @ficuscr The question seems pretty clear to me.  How to convince Doctrine to ignore selected database columns.  Perhaps you could show how?

Comment: Glad to. Show me your current code. You've provided more info I see. Show us the entity and what your annotations look like now. And not the obvious failure to clear cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

With Doctrine ORM you map your database table to a PHP class and a row from that table is mapped to an instance of the entity class.
So i am pretty sure that you have to map all your fields. Otherwise if you dont want to - user ActiveRecord, it is possible there.